# msal angular get a picture of the user

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm using with azure/msal-angular Library. and I'm trying to get a picture of the user profile.

This is me code in app.module.ts

```
MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: 'xxx',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
  }
}), {
  interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
  authRequest: {
    scopes: ['user.read']
    }
}, {
  interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
  protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
      ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
  ])
})
```